# preload assets images before build

Tags: dart, flutter

am trying to set background image of my container to image from assets like this:

```
return new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage(images[index]),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
```

but this will take some time to load and return blank whilte screen till image load ..

so i tried to preload images before build like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
precacheImage(new AssetImage(images[1]), context);
precacheImage(new AssetImage(images[2]), context);
precacheImage(new AssetImage(images[3]), context);
super.initState();
}
```

and this returned this error:

> flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   flutter: The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
>   flutter: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MediaQuery) or inheritFromElement() was called before
>   flutter: _WalkthroughPageState.initState() completed.
>   flutter: When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent
>   flutter: widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor
>   flutter: or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the
>   flutter: inherited widget.
>   flutter: Typically references to to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively,
>   flutter: initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which
>   flutter: is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.
>   flutter:
>   flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   flutter: #0      StatefulElement.inheritFromElement. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3898:9)
>   flutter: #1      StatefulElement.inheritFromElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3931:6)
>   flutter: #2      Element.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3274:14)
>   flutter: #3      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:476:38)
>   flutter: #4      createLocalImageConfiguration (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:49:34)
>   flutter: #5      precacheImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:81:37)
>   flutter: #6      _WalkthroughPageState.initState (package:spl/Pages/walkthrough.page.dart:65:5)
>   flutter: #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3808:58)
>   flutter: #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4838:14)
>   flutter: #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4838:14)
>   flutter: #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4838:14)
>   flutter: #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #28     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #29     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3826:11)
>   flutter: #30     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #33     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4838:14)
>   flutter: #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #38     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4838:14)
>   flutter: #43     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #45     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #46     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #47     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #48     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3826:11)
>   flutter: #49     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #50     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #51     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #52     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #53     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #54     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #55     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #56     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #58     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4838:14)
>   flutter: #59     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #60     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #61     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #62     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #63     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #64     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #65     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #66     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #67     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #68     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #69     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #70     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3826:11)
>   flutter: #71     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #72     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #73     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #74     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #75     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #76     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3679:5)
>   flutter: #77     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3826:11)
>   flutter: #78     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3674:5)
>   flutter: #79     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   flutter: #80     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   flutter: #81     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4621:32)
>   flutter: #82     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4953:17)
>   flutter: #83     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #84     _TheatreElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:507:16)
>   flutter: #85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #86     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #88     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3856:5)
>   flutter: #89     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #90     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #91     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #92     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3968:5)
>   flutter: #93     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #94     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4845:14)
>   flutter: #95     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #96     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #97     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #98     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3856:5)
>   flutter: #99     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #100    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4845:14)
>   flutter: #101    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #102    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4845:14)
>   flutter: #103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   flutter: #104    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3710:16)
>   flutter: #105    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   flutter: #106    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2286:33)
>   flutter: #107    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:676:20)
>   flutter: #108    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
>   flutter: #109    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
>   flutter: #110    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
>   flutter: #111    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
>   flutter: #112    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:13)
>   flutter: #113    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:140:3)
>   flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, the solution was in the error description itself:

> initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and
>   whenever the dependencies change thereafter.

Here's a simplified version of my code, preloading images in method *didChangeDependencies*:

```
class _SampleWidgetState extends State<SamleWidget> {
  Image image1;
  Image image2;
  Image image3;
  Image image4;

  Image currentImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    image1 = Image.asset("assets/image1.png");
    image2 = Image.asset("assets/image2.png");
    image3 = Image.asset("assets/image3.png");
    image4 = Image.asset("assets/image4.png");

    currentImage = image1;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    precacheImage(image1.image, context);
    precacheImage(image2.image, context);
    precacheImage(image3.image, context);
    precacheImage(image4.image, context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: currentImage,
    );
  }

  void setImage(int index) {
      switch (index) {
        case 1: currentImage = image1; break;
        case 2: currentImage = image2; break;
        case 3: currentImage = image3; break;
        case 4: currentImage = image4; break;
      }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think, you can try `FutureBuilder`

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

class MyImage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyImage(this._imgSrc);
  final String _imgSrc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Image image = Image.asset(_imgSrc);
    Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer<ui.Image>();
    image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info.image);
    });
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: completer.future,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData ? image : Container();
        });
  }
```

Comment: i got the error ui,image isn't a type can't be used as a type argument ...

Comment: @lamatat `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`

Comment: ok now the error is gone .. but i have three images .. how to do it? shall i repeat this three times for each image?

Comment: i want to test it but i need the three images so i can swipe between them and see if my issue is gone..

Comment: @lamatat use `Future.wait` for example

Comment: it did work .. still it takes less seconds to load .. and it cause the swiping process not smooth as if there is a lag when swiping ..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! but i figured out that the size of the image was very large .. and when i downsized it's size i got it solved .. thank you again for your help :)!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `precacheImage` is creating an `ImageConfiguration` object with the function `createLocalImageConfiguration`. And this function accesses some `InheritedWidget`.

And accessing `InheritedWidget` in constructor or in the initState method can be tricky.

Here is the `createLocalImageConfiguration` function, the one that access `InheritedWidget`

```dart
ImageConfiguration createLocalImageConfiguration(BuildContext context, { Size? size }) {
  return ImageConfiguration(
    bundle: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context),
    devicePixelRatio: MediaQuery.maybeOf(context)?.devicePixelRatio ?? 1.0,
    locale: Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context),
    textDirection: Directionality.maybeOf(context),
    size: size,
    platform: defaultTargetPlatform,
  );
}
```

To avoid this, as the error message advise you and as [Alex Domenici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766740/12267456) answered, you can move this code inside the `didUpdateWidget` method.

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin from pub.dev

```
cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
```

Example :-

```
CachedNetworkImage(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      // this is network image
                      imageUrl: reviewModel.carfrontImage!,
                      // preload assets images before build
                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(
                        'assets/image/red_car.png',
                        height: 80,
                        width: 80,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: i think this will be solve your issue