# How to store asset Images in cache in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, caching

I have some images to show in my application and those images are big in size so I want to store them in cache. On tap of a button I am changing all the images to other set of images and it looks bad when changing it as all of them load again and again. I tried many solutions but none works for me till now.

I tried using the method below but I see no difference in the loading of the images.

```
precacheImage(AssetImage("path"), context);
```

Is there a way to like save images so when I change the images they won't load again (Any package and its implementation or even dart code would do). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cached_network_image package. With that, you are able to display images. After showing them once, they are cached and easy to reuse.

Comment: Yeah, but I am talking about images in assets can it cache asset images? If it can then how to do it? Sorry I am new to this

Comment: For that, you could make use of the package asset_cache. On the other side the default implementation for such a behavior without any third party packages would look like https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766740/12791556

Comment: Hi I used many ways to do so and one of them was using the asset_cache package but still could not get the desired result and also the link you provided is already covered in my question stating that one of my methods was using `precacheImage`. Thanks for helping me out but can you provide a dummy code for reference ? (because probably I may be implementing them wrong)

Comment: There's a dummy code provided in the link. If yours looks the same, you're doing it correct. If it still needs some time to load, keep in mind, that if you are testing it on an emulator, most of them are pretty slow, so it could look different on a real device. If you use a real device, there's not much you can do about it anymore, saidly.